# error element type is invalid expected a string (for built-in components) but got: undefined after upgrading react and react-native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, upgrade

I upgraded my project from

"react": "16.11.0",
"react-native": "0.62.2",

to

"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.72.4",

With the react upgrader helper. But when i got to build it I get this error

[image]

I reseted my cache, delete node_modules and yarn.lock, cleaned muy gradlew and built the project with

```
npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

But I keep getting this error. It seems to be pointing to the bundle file but it doesn't specify from which component is from. Does anyone know how to fix it or how to find out which file is from?